# Populate listbox with alias values using SQL select statment

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, select, listbox

I have two columns in MS SQL table (ID, and Name) that I want to use to populate a list box with.  I would like to show the Name values (as alias?) in the list box, however when the user selects the item I want the ID value to be returned not the Name value.  My code below just adds the values into the list box from the Name column.

```
 Me.listName.Items.Clear()

 Dim strName As String  = "select SetName from " & tb

 Dim con As String = sConnectionString
 Dim com As New SqlCommand(strServiceType, New SqlConnection(con))
 com.Connection.Open()

 Dim dr As SqlDataReader
 Dim ColumnValue As String = Nothing

 dr = com.ExecuteReader
 While dr.Read
   ColumnValue = (dr.GetValue(0)).ToString
   listName.Items.Add(ColumnValue)
   listName.Sorted = True
 End While

 com.Connection.Close()
```

I'm not sure how to apply the logic above to get the associated ID value besides running another select statement on the list box SelectedIndexChanged event.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, you simply need to edit your sql to pull both ID and Name, then edit your addition of an item to your list box to add a new list item instead.

i.e.

```
listName.Items.Add(New ListItem("TEXT","VALUE"))
```

Comment: where is ListItem coming from?  Is it a list variable?  My code complete does not show this option for my list box.

Comment: so each item in your list (listName) is and instance of the class ListItem, this simply creates one before adding it to the list itself.